# Escaped backslash in path in .cmake is not recognized properly under win10

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, windows-10, vcpkg

Originally I wanted to make my own simple script to sync my HDD to MEGA cloud, as descktop app continues to crush. Wanted to use [python package](https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py), but it is unofficial and don't support 2FA.
OK, mega has [c++ sdk](https://github.com/meganz/sdk) and [megacmd](https://github.com/meganz/megacmd).

Although i need **megacmd** I'm encountering errors while compiling **SKD**. So I downloaded SDK, installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, cmake 3.24.2, and following instructions.
First, in [x64-windows-mega.cmake](https://github.com/meganz/sdk/blob/master/contrib/cmake/vcpkg_extra_triplets/x64-windows-mega.cmake) I had to replace \\ with \ for set(VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH ...), otherwise getting error:

```
Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance
    at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\"
    with toolset version v142
The following Visual Studio instances were considered:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
The following paths were examined for Visual Studio instances:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary/Build\vcvarsall.bat
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC/vcvarsall.bat
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC/bin\dumpbin.exe
```

Same error if \\ replaced with /. Also tried to replace `set` with `file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/" VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH)`

But then I'm getting error here:

```
CMake Error at buildtrees/0.vcpkg_tags.cmake:9 (set):,   Syntax error in cmake code at, ,     mega/3rdparty_sdk/vcpkg/buildtrees/0.vcpkg_tags.cmake:9, ,   when parsing string, ,     Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community, ,   Invalid character escape '\P'., Call Stack (most recent call first):,   buildtrees/0.vcpkg_tags.cmake:52 (vcpkg_triplet_file),   buildtrees/0.vcpkg_tags.cmake:84 (vcpkg_get_tags), , ,
```

Content of [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/meganz/sdk/blob/master/contrib/cmake/CMakeLists.txt) and [build_from_scratch.cmake](https://github.com/meganz/sdk/blob/master/contrib/cmake/build_from_scratch.cmake)

As it copy strings from **x64-windows-mega.cmake** with unescaped \. How to fix slash escaping?
CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please explain what the reason was for doing "I had to replace \\ with \". If you replace \\, it should be /, but the first issue was not caused by the double slashes.

Comment: Windows (in all contexts) recognises a forward slash as a path separator, so you can use that

Comment: @273K Visual studio, sorry. Getting same error if \\ replaced with /. Only \ works

Comment: Have you checked Desktop Development components in Visual Studio installer?

Comment: @273K can you be more specific? I'm not pro in c++, just following instructions.

Comment: ***Getting same error if \\ replaced with /. Only \ works*** Very odd. I have used CMake + Visual Studio + Qt since at work 2008 (for most of my software development as a medical imaging research software engineer) and never recall having  `/` fail except for UNC paths but I don't use that with CMake.

Comment: If you can provide more information please do so. Perhaps a fragment of your CMakeLists.txt, I don't fully understand the error message and how you got into this situation.

Comment: @drescherjm it's all from mega sdk repo I mentioned in question.

Comment: I understand that but from the point of view of someone volunteering to help you. It's a quite a bit of effort to download this toolkit and attempt to replicate the same issue you are having. If you can make the problem easier for us to help you may be able to get a faster answer.

Comment: @drescherjm added hyperlinks

Comment: hmm try removing the trailing/last slash \
but from:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary/Build\vcvarsall.bat
i would assume you are just missing components of the toolset

Comment: @AlexanderNeumann 1) With/without trailing slash have no effect: works with \ dose not works with \\ or / or file(... 2) If something is missing, then why it not faling with same error with \? 3) Anyway have no Build folder in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\, but have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC/vcvarsall.bat

Comment: > Anyway have no Build folder in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\`  
--------------
You are forcing vcpkg to use VS2019 but don't have the required stuff installed?